# rewinding stdin in a bash script

Tags: bash, pointers, redirect, pipe, stdin

Is there a simple way to "rewind" `/dev/stdin` inside my bash script which already read all or some portion from the input pipe?

Application: I wrote a simple MDA that in part 1, reads a single email from fetchmail line by line, like so:

```
while read -a linA; do
    echo -e "$[++linenum]:\t${#linA[@]},${linA[*]}" > /dev/null  # verbose
    [ "${linA[0]}" = "Date:" ] && unset linA[0] && mailDate="${linA[*]}"
    [ "${linA[0]}" = "Subject:" ] && unset linA[0] && mailSubject="${linA[*]}"
    [ "$mailSubject" = "Courtesy Fill Notification" ] || break  # if wrong subject then thank you, we're done with this mail
done
```

and at the end of processing, I wish to save the entire message into a file, both for debugging, and so that the writer-side of the pipe sees that its entire output had been read, and not return failure (therefore keeping the message as unread in the mailbox).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading a pipe is destructive; there is no way to seek on a pipe:

```
ESPIPE (29): Illegal seek
```

The error number is from MacOS X, but the name is traditional (and POSIX-mandated) and gives an indication of where the restriction comes from.

So, if you want to reprocess input in a shell script, you will need to stash the standard input away in a file so you can reprocess it:

```
tmp=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/xx.$$    # Consider mktemp or something
trap "rm -f $tmp.1; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15  # Exit, HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE, TERM

tee $tmp.1 |
while read -a linA
do
    ...
done

...reprocess $tmp.1 here...

rm -f $tmp.1
trap 0
exit $exit_status
```

The only trap to watch is that because of the pipeline, variables set in the `while` loop are not accessible in the parent shell.  If that's a problem, you can use:

```
tee $tmp.1 |
{
while read -a linA
do
    ...
done

...reprocess $tmp.1 here...
}
```

The braces group the statements for I/O redirection purposes.  The `tee` process will have completed because of EOF so the file will be complete when the `while read` detects EOF, so it is safe to access `$tmp.1` after the loop.

The one thing to watch is that `tee` will make this unresponsive to terminal input.  Files won't be a problem; piped input is unlikely to be a problem.  However, `tee` will probably fully buffer its output, rather than line buffering its output, so the read loop may not see anything until you've typed many lines of input.

Comment: ++ because I like your bash tricks in the first three code lines.  My mda.sh script is always used non-interactively anyway...even for testing I redirect/cat a test file to it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what code did you attempt to seek with to get that `ESPIPE` error?  I may use for non-pipe cases.

Comment: I actually ran a program I wrote/generated called `errno` that prints the information corresponding to an error number specified numerically or as a string (I specified ESPIPE).  You would get it if you do: `int p[2], e; pipe(p); lseek(p[0], -1L, 2); e = errno; printf("%d (%s)\n", e, strerror(e));`, except the symbolic name is harder to get than that.  (I have a Perl script to generate the actual code of `errno`.)

Comment: Okay so you did that in `C`. No wonder I couldn't find any mention of _seek_ or input buffer/stream _cursor_ in `man bash`

Comment: Checkmark for most useful answer. Willing to accept there might not be a direct way.  Besides for now I switched my code around to `tee pee.txt | while read -a linA; do` plus logic to later just delete/rename that intermediate file if it wasn't meant to be created in the first place.

Comment: Oh man...I just spent a few puzzled hours troubleshooting and a day's worth of failed email-based triggers (which I now have to manually correct in the affected accounts) because I overlooked your warning about the pipeline leading to destroyed local subshell variables. Having thought it's some subtle `IMAP <==> fetchmail <==> MDA` interaction issue. Thanks again!  So you say if I surround my **while loop** with `{ }` the variables set within should stay for afterwards?

Comment: Yes - if the code that needs the variables is all in the scope of either `{ ... }` as shown or (possibly, but not recommended, within `( ... )` - though the difference is minor for the most part), then you'll be OK.  Bad luck on the wasted time; I tried... :D

Comment: The code that needs the variables follows the while loop till end of script, therefore seems I need to somehow globalize everything that gets created inside the new `{ ... }` block, or a wider code restructure. Lots of semi-dynamic vars get generated in there depending on the message body. Shoot. At least now I know what I'm facing. Part of me reconsidering the tee pipe thing.

Comment: Sounds like the sane part of you may be doing the reconsidering :D  Or the 'will be sane after fixing this insanity' part of you.  Consider breaking it up into two separate scripts, too; a small one that decides on the temporary file name and then runs: `tee $tmp.1 | new-script $tmp.1` (passing the new script the tee'd file name).  Or, instead of all this, simply change the script to do:
`cat >$tmp.1` (instead of `tee $tmp.1 | ...`).  Then redirect the primary input loop (`while read ...`) from `$tmp.1`.  Since there is no pipeline, the should be no problems that weren't there before.

Comment: Experimented for a time with `declare -gx`, `export` and `eval` but `cat >$mailmsg; while read -a linA; do ... done < $mailmsg` was cleanest and avoided the subshell that destroyed my data in the first place. Thanks for the tip yet again. A [good site on such pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Answer (score 1):

Try `exec < /dev/stdin` which might work under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no.

You'll just have to append each line into a variable as you read it and clear the variable as needed.

Comment: except often the loop exits early from a `break`

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
while read -a linA; do
  echo -e "$[++linenum]:\t${#linA[@]},${linA[*]}" > /dev/null  # verbose
  [ "${linA[0]}" = "Date:" ] && unset linA[0] && mailDate="${linA[*]}"
  echo "${linA}">>$tmpfile
done
mv $tmpfile fulltext.txt
```

I think it's better way because you read message just once

Comment: Thanks. Because I intend to keep the input into a file anyway, I think I will skip this whole _tmpfilename_ business and (over)write a fixed filename at the start, rather than end, of my script. Would need to slightly change my loop for that.  So I think I might go with something like `cat /dev/stdin > $inputfile` followed by `cat $inputfile | while read -a ...`